# react-native-admob doesn't show any ads

Tags: react-native

Here is my code. 
But it only displays two red dots. No errors and so on.  Any ideas what is wrong? Thanks

```
... import {
    AdMobBanner,
} from 'react-native-admob'

export default class AboutApp extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style ={styles.container}>

                <AdMobBanner
                    bannerSize="fullBanner"
                    adUnitID="ca-app-pub-7257084341937***/7776***"
                    testDeviceID="EMULATOR"
                    didFailToReceiveAdWithError={this.bannerError} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, do you test it on an emulator? If so, you can use test ad id to see if the problem is about your ad account or something general. And ios or android?

Comment: @EnieJakiro Thanks! It is on Android and what do you mean by test ad id?

Comment: can you try this https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/issues/38

Comment: @EnieJakiro rebuild all dependencies and updated to RN 0.42 - and now everything is ok. Thanks

Comment: Glad you solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the View tag, Ads will appear. It's a strange behavior I faced.